# (Why) Does this limit exist? (Contingent derivative)

Tags: limits, derivatives, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f \colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R \cup \{ \infty \}$ be proper and lower semicontinuous.
Let $x, u \in (\mathbb R^d, | \cdot |_2)$ with $0 < | u |_2 \le 1$.
Choose sequences $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ and $(v_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb R^d$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n}
= \liminf_{\substack{t \searrow 0 \\ v \to u}} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t v)}{t}.
$$
The limit on the left side exists.

**My question**
Does the limit
\begin{equation} \tag{$\star$} \label{eq:1}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n | v_n |_2}
\end{equation}
exist, too?

**Ideas.**
The following limit exists:
\begin{equation} \tag{$\star \star$} \label{eq:2}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n | u |_2}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n | v_n |_2} \frac{| v_n |_2}{| u |_2}.
\end{equation}
We know that $\frac{| v_n |_2}{| u |_2} \to 1$ and that the product of the limits is the limit of the product if both limits exists.
Since $| v_n | \to | u |$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $| | v_n |_2 - | u |_2 | < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$.
Hence for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n (| u |_2 + \varepsilon)}
\le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n | v_n |_2}
\le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n (| u |_2 - \varepsilon)}.
$$
Both the outer left and the outer right limit exist and for $\varepsilon \searrow 0$ converge to the middle one. Is this enough to conclude that \eqref{eq:1} exists and is equal to \eqref{eq:2}?

Comment: So, $X\subseteq \mathbb R^d?$

Comment: Your last inequalities must be reversed if the numerator is $<0.$

Comment: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n}=L,$
why not simply write $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x) - f(x + t_n v_n)}{t_n | v_n |_2}=L/\lim_{n \to \infty}| v_n |_2=L/|u|_2?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In fact, $X = \mathbb R^d$, I edited accordingly  (even though nothing should change if we replace $\mathbb R^d$ by any Banach space).

Comment: @AnneBauval That is true, but I think we only need the inequalities for sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$, so we can restricty ourselves to $\varepsilons < | u |_2$.

Comment: I am talking about the numerator of the three terms, not the denominator of the last one. Anyway, what about my second comment? (it says that the answer to your question is obviously yes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last inequalities must be reversed if the numerator is $<0.$

Anyway, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x+t_nv_n)}{t_n}=L,$ simply write
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x+t_nv_n)}{t_n|v_n|_2}=\frac L{\lim_{n\to \infty}|v_n |_2}=\frac L{|u|_2}.$$